# SQL Basic Syntax

Tags: sql

I have the following problem:

[image: Problem]

What happens if the query didn't ask for B in the select?. I think it would give an error because the aggregate is computed based on the values in the select clause.

I have the following relation schema and queries:

Suppose R(A,B)  is  a   relation    with    a   single  tuple   (NULL,  NULL).

```
SELECT  A,  COUNT(B)
FROM    R
GROUP   BY  A; 

SELECT  A,  COUNT(*)
FROM    R
GROUP   BY  A; 

SELECT  A,  SUM(B)
FROM    R
GROUP   BY  A;
```

The first query returns NULL and 0. I am not sure about what the second query returns. The aggregate COUNT(*) count the number of tuples in one table; however, I don't know what it does to a group. The third returns NULL,NULL

Comment: _The third returns NULL,NULL_ Given that data, this is not what happens, unless this is some kind of wierd dialect of SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only rule about `SELECT` and `GROUP BY` is that the unaggregated columns in the `SELECT` *must be* in the `GROUP BY` (with very specific exceptions).

You can have columns in the `GROUP BY` that never appear in the `SELECT`. That is fine. It doesn't affect the definition of a group, but multiple rows may seem to have the same values in the `GROUP BY` columns.

Comment: what would the first query return without a B like SELECT A SUM(C), MAX(D)

Comment: For example, if we have two tuples in the form $a1b1$ and $a1b2$ if we just put select A then in the aggregate SUM(C), would it compute the sum of both groups?

Comment: @daniel . . . I'm not sure I understand the comments.  The query will return the columns specified in the `select` with the rows defined by the `group by`.

Comment: ,ok what would the query return without the attributes A and B in the select clause?

Comment: @daniel . . . You have to have something in the `SELECT`.  That is what is returned.

Comment: that's what I can't understand. How do the aggregates behave based on the listed attributes in the select clause. For example, select A,B,SUM(C),MAX(D)  takes the group a1b1 and SUM(C) sums the non-null values in C of group a1b1. What happens if you just have select A,SUM(C),MAX(D). How does SUM(C) and MAX(D) compute their value based on the attribute A in the select clause?

Comment: @daniel . . .Once again:  The `GROUP BY` defines the rows.  The `SELECT` defines the columns.